# .htaccess поддомен

Tags: .htaccess, поддомены

Поддомены средствами .htaccess работают как нужно:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z]+)\.site\.ru
RewriteRule ^(.*) modules/shop/index.php?name=%1 [L]
```

Но как мне сделать так, чтобы например когда я заходил на domain.site.ru/install, выполнялось следующее:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) modules/shop/install.php [L]
```

То есть domain.site.ru уже есть, теперь как прикрутить domain.site.ru/install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну у тебя же уже правило первое обрабатывает все запросы и параметр L говорит о том, что правило это последнее и после него ничего не будет обрабатываться (если правило входит в url строку). Тебе нужно просто второе правило поставить выше и написать типа:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z]+)\.site\.ru
RewriteRule ^install/(.*) modules/shop/install.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) modules/shop/index.php?name=%1 [L]
```

Comment: @lampa, в Вашем случае, у меня почему-то сам site.ru начинает отображать содержимое файла modules/shop/index.php и соответственно, не помогло.

Comment: @ModaL ах да, по моему нужно rewritecond подставить перед каждым правилом, по другому второе правило будет для всего сайта работать. Еще как-то можно с <VirtualHost *>, но это уже в httpd.conf.